# Search or list assembly symbols with gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm trying to debug a kernel I'm writing for a course using GDB attaching to QEMU. It's a mix of assembly and C code, compiled with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` and the `-g` flag.

For the C code I can search for functions and variables using GDB commands such as `info functions <regex>` and `info variables <regex>` and all works fine, however that never returns functions/labels from the assembly code.

The assembly symbols are clearly loaded and resolved, as I can set breakpoints and list code using the labels (see below), but how can I list or search such assembly symbols?

```
(gdb) b start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80000: file boot.s, line 5.
(gdb) list delay
11          mrs x0, currentel
12          lsr x0, x0, #2
13          ret
14
15      delay:
16          subs x0, x0, #1
17          bne delay
18          ret
(gdb) info functions delay
All functions matching regular expression "delay":
(gdb)
```

Comment: GDB might be filtering symbols by their type metadata. `.type   delay, %function` like GCC uses when generating asm (https://godbolt.org/z/xv49f87TG) might make GDB see it as a *function* symbol, instead of just an unknown symbol, and you did ask for functions specifically, not all symbols.  And/or possibly `.globl delay` could be relevant to export the symbol, but probably GDB doesn't treat linker-visible symbols differently from "debug" symbols that aren't actually exported.